# Placing jQuery trigger icon inside asp.net textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker, custom-controls

I want to use the [jQuery **default** date picker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger), it's awesome, but I want to put the trigger icon inside an asp.net textbox on the right side. How can I achieve this? Maybe using a custom asp.net control?

Thank you.

```
<asp:textbox id="sht" runat="server" />
<script> $('#sht').datepicker();</script>
```

Comment: can you give some example, what icon are you talking about ? how is this code on html ? Give some links for what code are you referred to ?

Comment: Why someone down vote this question ?!

Comment: @Aristos the icon trigger comes with jquery datepicker pluggin, does not matter what icon is, just want to put it inside text box, I think the question it's clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look this example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/zy7YP/1/)

CSS:

```
.icon {
background:#FFFFFF url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista-   2/16/Start-Menu-Search-icon.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
padding:4px 4px 4px 22px;
height:18px;
}
```

​HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="sample" class="icon">​
```

Comment: This helps me a lot, but how can I put the icon on the right side?

Comment: Just Add 'background-position:right;' to the css lke below: `.icon { background:#FFFFFF url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista- 2/16/Start-Menu-Search-icon.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;'background-position:right; padding:4px 4px 4px 22px; height:18px; }`